# Running BQ from sheets. How to estimate Jobs cost before running?

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

I built a more or less simple Gsheets-UI for the management to run specific requests on BigQuery. However, bigger requests might cost a lot of $, so I'm asked to tell them before the job runs how much it is expected to cost.

Within Bigquery-UI, there is the `green V` that tells how much GB the job will pass. From this number I can infer the cost. But how can I know it in the Script before the job is sent?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the BigQuery API in your script. If  the query is valid and if you set [**dryRun**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query#dryRun) to true, BigQuery doesn't run the job. Instead, BigQuery returns statistics about the job such as how many bytes would be processed.

Here you have more information that may be useful: [Price your queries before running them](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs#price_your_queries_before_running_them).

Answer (score 1):

You can do dry run first, which returns number of bytes query will process. Note, however that there is a minimum amount of bytes billed: 10M per query and 10M per table. So the final cost will be max(bytes_processed, 10M, n_tables * 10M).